# Google Adwords - batch process of searching for new keywords and ad group ideas?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using Google Adwords' Keyword Planner to search for new keywords and ad group ideas for a long list of items.  I was wondering if there was a way to do process a bunch of keywords.  I can't seem to find that functionality in the page itself or a command to invoke it via the API (where I can write a script to parse a csv of keywords on a regular basis).

Answer (score 1):

I saw an example of getting keywords ideas in the php lib api :

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/tree/master/examples/AdWords/v201402/Optimization

you will find the example in GetKeywordIdeas.php